# Meaning of 'i' in function names `cusparse<t>axpyi` and `cusparse<t>doti`

Tags: cuda, cusparse

`cusparse<t>axpyi` and `cusparse<t>doti` are function names in [cuSPARSE](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html), the CUDA sparse matrix library.

The [naming conventions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#naming-convention) section explains `<t>` denotes data types, and `axpyi`, `doti`, `roti` all denote operations. However it does not further explain what the 'i' means in those names.

*FYI, `cusparse<t>axpyi` performs **`a * x + y`** (so I guess 'axpy' means 'ax plus y').

 `cusparse<t>doti` performs **dot product** of a sparse vector `x` and a dense vector `y`.

`cusparse<t>roti` performs **rotations** (actually I'm not clear on how that works either).*

Comment: cusparse is following the [sparse BLAS](https://www.netlib.org/sparse-blas/) naming conventions, I believe

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delayed reply. After some digging, now I know the answer. Would you mind that I post the result as the answer below? (Or maybe you could do that?)

Comment: Go ahead and answer it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank @talonmies for the info!

Very likely cuSPARSE is following the [sparse BLAS](https://www.netlib.org/sparse-blas/) naming conventions (read the paper therein):

> If a sparse BLAS routine is an extension of a dense BLAS, the subprogram name
>   is formed by appending a suffix character, `I`, standing for ***indexed***,
>   to the dense name.

---

Or you can read that from the [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-naming-conventions-for-sparse-blas-routines) website (which is much more direct):

> If a sparse BLAS routine is an extension of a "dense" one, the subprogram name is formed by appending the suffix `i` (standing for ***indexed***) to the name of the corresponding "dense" subprogram.